# Объединение список словарей без потери данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно правильно и оптимально соединить 3 списка словарей в один? У всех ключи одинаковые, а вот начинка разная.
Пример данных:

```
list_1 = [{'Client': [345, 12612],
  'description': '19T',
  'user': 'test1'},
  {'Client': [158, 126],
  'description': '45T',
  'user': 'test1'}]
list_2 = [{'Client': [15128, 13126],
  'description': '9T',
  'user': 'test 2'},
  {'Client': [158, 126],
  'description': '11T',
  'user': 'test2'}]
list_3 = [{'Client': [123, 41],
  'description': '5T',
  'user': 'test3'},
  {'Client': [158, 126],
  'description': ' 14T',
  'user': 'test3'}]
```

И в итоге должно получиться так:

```
list_new = [{'Client': [345, 12612],
      'description': '19T',
      'user': 'test1'},
      {'Client': [158, 126],
      'description': '45T',
      'user': 'test1'},
     {'Client': [15128, 13126],
      'description': '9T',
      'user': 'test 2'},
      {'Client': [158, 126],
      'description': '11T',
      'user': 'test2'},
      {'Client': [123, 41],
      'description': '5T',
      'user': 'test3'},
      {'Client': [158, 126],
      'description': ' 14T',
      'user': 'test3'}]
```

Comment: вам же уже вчера ответ давали, вы его даже приняли. что-то изменилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша задача решается одной строкой
`list_new = list_1+list_2+list_3`